# why are the addresses of these variables printing as ab@ and b@?

Tags: c++, memory-address

I run the follow code:

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    typedef struct Test
    {
        char   a;
        char   b;
        int    i;
        double d;
    }Test;

    int main()
    {
        Test test;
        test.a = 'a';
        test.b = 'b';
        test.i = 478;
        test.d = 4.7;

        cout << &test.a << '\n'
             << &test.b << '\n'
             << &test.i << '\n'
             << &test.d << '\n';

        return 0;
    }
```

The output is:

```
    ab@
    b@
    0x28fe94
    0x28fe98
```

At first, i thought it is a result of the precedence between `&` and `.`.
But the `0x28fe94` and `0x28fe94` indicate it's not the problem of precedence.
I can figure out what does the `ab@` and `b@` mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write

```
 cout << &test.a
```

because `test.a` is a `char`, this will invoke the `operator<< (ostream&, const char*)` overload, thinking that your `char*` is a pointer to a C-style string rather than a pointer to just one character. Consequently, the operation will start reading bytes starting at the memory address of `&test.a` until it finds a null terminator (a zero byte). This happens to print out `ab@`, since `a` has value `'a'`, `b` has value `'b'`, and the number 478, on your system, happens to correspond to an `@` character followed eventually by a null byte.

If you want to see the numeric addresses of `test.a` and `test.b`, cast the pointers to `void*`s, which will select the `operator<< (ostream&, const void*)` overload. For example:

```
cout << static_cast<void*>(&test.a)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

It means undefined behaviour. There's a special overload for `const char *` that prints it as a null-terminated string. Yours has no terminator, so it goes beyond and triggers the aforementioned UB. Fix it with a cast:

```
std::cout << static_cast<void *>(&test.a) << '\n'
          << static_cast<void *>(&test.b) << '\n'
          << &test.i << '\n'
          << &test.d << '\n';
```

Comment: Is this really undefined behavior, given that the fields are given numeric values, or is it unspecified?

Comment: @templatetypedef, Well, I got a different output on Coliru, so there's a start. It's likely something will happen with the other members, but to my knowledge, they could be rearranged as long as they appear in that order (appearing to doesn't include this behaviour), so it could technically be last, going with the whole biggest to smallest size, and could have padding, and I'm not sure whether that requires 0 bytes. Might as well mention the possibility of not ASCII, too, for the heck of it, but you knew that already. I'm all for your explanation of what's actually happening, though.

Comment: @templatetypedef: there's no guarantee of structure packing (indeed, it's unlikely given the data types in use) so there may be uninitialised memory between the fields that's first read during streaming of the assumed ASCIIZ string... don't all uninitialised reads have undefined behaviour?  I'd have to check the Standard again.  Only likely to bite if the CPU support writes to particular bytes in a machine word, and the compiler uses such instructions, but that's not a ridiculous supposition.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are passing the address of a character when you use `&test.a` and `&test.b`, the `cout` operator is treating the addresses as the start of a string.  That's why you get first `ab@` and then `b@`.  The `@` is less obvious; it falls in the padding after the two `char` values and before the `int` value in the structure, and is quasi random junk.  You're actually invoking undefined behaviour because you're asking the output code to access the padding.  If you want to print addresses, cast to `void *`.  If you want to print characters, don't supply the address.